# Included ConstraintLayout deosn't fix position when TextView has two lines

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I've got `ConstraintLayout` which contains `TextView` and includes other `ConstraintLayout`. The reason why I include other constraint is that in this project I'm using an old version of support library(26.1.0) which doesn't contain groups and currently I'm not able to upgrade it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topTitleTextView"
    style="@style/TextBigMinus"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_normal"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_normal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_normal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/included_part"
    layout="@layout/included_part"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topTitleTextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm setting my `text` straight from the code and on different devices, it can have one or two lines. When it has two lines, the included part will be moved by the height of the line but should be resized as it has an `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`.

What causes that and how it could be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`
and set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine as per your requirement

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/included_part"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/included_part"
            layout="@layout/included_part"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topTitleTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the included part to move as the height of the text line changes also get resized to fit in the available screen, having the `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` won't work on layouts that include views (`TextView`, `ImageView` etc), nested included layouts with fixed height values in dp or sp unit. Make sure the included view has every height attribute set to 0dp inside `ConstraintLayout` and then use this code where I've fixed the constraint fields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topTitleTextView"
    style="@style/TextBigMinus"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_normal"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_normal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_normal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/included_part"
    layout="@layout/included_part"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topTitleTextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The text view bottom is constraint to parent, while the included part bottom also constraint to parent. This will resulted of some part of the view overlap each other. Try to remove app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" on the text view property.